# Area 51 Newest Proposals ordering appears to be wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, sorting

I'm really not sure this ordering is right:

[image]

It appears on [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=newest), about [2/3 of the way down](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=newest#proposal-summary-89732).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct. The Ethereum proposal attracted very much attention during the definition phase because it was posted at several other places, including the SubReddit about Ethereum. See also the [relevant discussion on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21493/something-smells-fishy).

The other proposals were most likely only followed by some users who happened to pass by, so those are less active.

Comment: Wow. That was some fast growth!

Comment: @Tim Yes, but it slowed down recently, and I personally think that they will have a challenge getting the 100 committers with 200 rep on another site.